# Django Vue3 access-control-allow-origin is not allowed

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Django rest-api project. Vue is used on the front of the project. I get the following error when requesting via Vue:

print console:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.iyziwell.com/api/user/login' from origin 'https://main.d398abgajqt044.amplifyapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'webpack_loader',
    'account',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',   
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'corsheaders',

]
```

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]
```

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'https://main.d398abgajqt044.amplifyapp.com',
    'http://localhost:8082',
]
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
    'https://main.d398abgajqt044.amplifyapp.com',
    'http://localhost:8082',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
)
```

request page = https://main.d398abgajqt044.amplifyapp.com

urls.py ,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index'),
    path('api/client/',include('client.api.urls')),
    path('api/user/',include('account.api.urls')),
    path('api/appointment/',include('appointment.api.urls')),
    path('api/user/login', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/user/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('api/password-reset/', include('django_rest_passwordreset.urls', namespace='password-reset')),
]
```

/ when I add

Error:

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

I can send requests with Postman.

Comment: in your `MIDDLEWARE` block, `django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware` has been duplicated.
`corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` has to come before `django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware`. remove the first

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

**Add this code to the file settings.py**

INSTALLED_APPS = [

```
'corsheaders',
```

]

MIDDLEWARE = [

```
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
```

]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True